# Java MAP to JSON

Tags: java, json

First of all, I'm new to Java so please be kind with me :-).

I have a map and I want to parse into JSON Object:

```
private static final Map<String, Queue<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, Queue<String>>();
```

My Key is the login (email) of a user.
I would like to create a JSON Object like this one :

```
{
    Login1: {
       itemOne: 'item one',
       itemTwo: 'item two'
    },
    Login2: {
       itemOne: 'item one',
       itemTwo: 'item two'
    }
}
```

I have tried it using JSONObject or ObjectMapper but it didn't worked. I'm looking for some tips / advices.

Thanks,

Comment: First of all, your example of your JSON representation is incorrect. Secondly, do you want the value in the `Queue` to be the value of the key?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it now, parsing `Map<String, Queue<String>>` into valid JSON would mean that you'd get something like this:

```
{
  queueOne: {
    itemOne: 'item one',
    itemTwo: 'item two'
  },
  queueTwo: {
    itemOne: 'item one',
    itemTwo: 'item two'
  }
}
```

If there's only one queue, putting it in a map isn't necessary. If there's multiple you'll have to iterate over the Map, create a JSONArray from the Queue and then put a JSONObject with the String as key and Queue as value into a main JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, but the key of your map is never used in your example.

Completed example would be:

```
{
  "key":{
    "item2":"SecondItemOnTheQueue",
    "item1":"FirstItemOnTheQueue",
    "item3":"ThirdItemOnTheQueue"
  }
}
```

Java code below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Queue<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Queue<String>>();

        map.put("key", new LinkedList<String>(){{
            add("FirstItemOnTheQueue");
            add("SecondItemOnTheQueue");
            add("ThirdItemOnTheQueue");
        }});

        System.out.println(generateFromMapOfQueues(map));
    }

    private static JSONObject generateFromMapOfQueues(Map<String, Queue<String>> map) {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(); 


        for(String key : map.keySet()){
            JSONObject queueJson = new JSONObject();
            int initSize = map.get(key).size();
            for (int i = 0; i < initSize; i++) {
                queueJson.append("item" + (i + 1), map.get(key).poll());
            }
            result.put(key, queueJson);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The map after completion will contain empty queues... That's the only problem.